# Downloading videos in FLV format from YouTube

Tags: python, download, youtube, urllib2

I can’t really understand how YouTube serves videos, but I have been reading through what I can.

It seems like the old method *get_video* is now obsolete and can't be used any more. Is there another Pythonic and simple method for collecting YouTube  videos?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might have some luck with youtube-dl

http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/documentation.html

I'm not sure if there's a good API, but it's written in Python, so theoretically you could do something a little better than Popen :)

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a url that gets generated or something along those lines, I had a look at youtube-dl it seemed alittle odd in its design method, thanks for your answer but I still cant work out the method

Comment: I think the get_video method was disabled in July, according to what I'm seeing when I google for it.  Sorry :(

Comment: +1 In the end, youtube-dl is a sophisticated wrapper around a GET request - but it may be useful to see what else needs to happen for the download to start successfully.

Comment: Does it still work (not a rhetorical question)? Is it kept up-to-date with the changes by YouTube (deliberately to break the downloaders)?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a quick Python script which downloads a YouTube video. No bells and whistles, just scrapes out the necessary URLs, hits the generate_204 URL and then streams the data to a file:

```
import lxml.html
import re
import sys
import urllib
import urllib2

_RE_G204 = re.compile('"(http:.+.youtube.com.*\/generate_204[^"]+")', re.M)
_RE_URLS = re.compile('"fmt_url_map": "(\d*[^"]+)",.*', re.M)

def _fetch_url(url, ref=None, path=None):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    headers = {}
    if ref:
        headers['Referer'] = ref
    request = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    if not path:
        return handle.read()
    sys.stdout.write('saving: ')
    # Write result to file
    with open(path, 'wb') as out:
        while True:
            part = handle.read(65536)
            if not part:
                break
            out.write(part)
            sys.stdout.write('.')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write('\nFinished.\n')

def _extract(html):
    tree = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
    res = {'204': _RE_G204.findall(html)[0].replace('\\', '')}
    for script in tree.findall('.//script'):
        text = script.text_content()
        if 'fmt_url_map' not in text:
            continue
        # Found it. Extract the URLs we need
        for tmp in _RE_URLS.findall(text)[0].split(','):
            url_id, url = tmp.split('|')
            res[url_id] = url.replace('\\', '')
        break
    return res

def main():
    target = sys.argv[1]
    dest = sys.argv[2]
    html = _fetch_url(target)
    res = dict(_extract(html))
    # Hit the 'generate_204' URL first and remove it
    _fetch_url(res['204'], ref=target)
    del res['204']
    # Download the video. Now I grab the first 'download' URL and use it.
    first = res.values()[0]
    _fetch_url(first, ref=target, path=dest)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running it:

```
python youdown.py 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Je_iqbgGXFw' stevegadd.flv
saving: ........................... finished.
```

Comment: You were so close to winning the bounty! It throws an exception.

Comment: Now it doesn't. The re is broken youtube did an update. Your not going to get the bounty till thats fixed

Comment: I generalized the url extraction regexp, and now uses the first 'videoplayback' url it finds. Tried it on several different videos, seems ok.

Comment: this doesn't work with `python 3.3.0`. It gives lots of error. Anyway, could you explain please the idea so that I could rewrite this on my own? What is `generate_204 url`? and what do you mean by *"hits the generate_204 url and then streams the data to a file"*?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend writing your own parser using urllib2 or [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup). You can look at the source code for [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/development/source-code/) to see how that plugin finds the video URL.