# Download video from youtube in my android app

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have integrated Youtube api in my android app. it play video in youtubeplayerview. Now i want to give option for downloading or see offline. Can it possible to download video from my app or to give functionality to see offline.

Comment: I believe it is prohibited by YouTube policies.

Answer (score 0):

No, it wont be possible as far as i know. Downloading video will violate their term and policies. check this link might help [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081676/how-to-download-a-youtube-video-using-the-youtubes-api)

Comment: I found a link http://www.ytsdk.com/. They provide sdk for downloading youtube video, But i can't understand how can we use it