# Can I record and upload video on Youtube API?

Tags: web, youtube-api

Can I use the YoutubeAPI on a web-app to record and save/upload a video with out it being broadcast live?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youtube does not support recording straight to their platform anymore.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/57409?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Use the method [Videos: insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert?csw=1) to upload video using YouTube api. About saving/downloading, I think, it's against their [Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/t/terms).

> `You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or
>   similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content`.

You can see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8081676/how-to-download-a-youtube-video-using-the-youtubes-api) for further reference on downloading content in YouTube.