# Process audio data in Google+ Hangout API

Tags: android, audio, google-plus

Is it possible to intercept audio data using google+ hangout api? I writing an app using g+ hangout for android and I would like to process the audio. To be precessive, I want to denoise speech and use speech-to-text (e.g. google search, sphinx) to make basic voice commands.

Because I have full control of the android app it doesn't matter for me if I will have a callback with audio data from hangout or I can record audio using android `AudioRecorder` and then somehow forward those data to google hangout (Though the latter solution would be better because we can denoise on the android device). Actually I would be happy with any feasible workaround that may work at this stage of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hangouts API](http://developers.google.com/+/hangouts) is not going to help you develop this feature.

What you need is a platform agnostic API for accessing hangouts data. The API is instead intended to solve a different problem. It allows you to write HTML/JavaScript applications that run inside the canvas of hangouts running on desktop web browsers.

Comment: is there any workaround to that? Right now the only think that comes to my mind is  to reverse engineer google+ android app to check how to create hangout and feed data to it.

Comment: There's no workaround that I know of right now. 

Reverse engineering may turn something up, but it will not be a supported API so it's quite likely that the resulting hack would break when the application is updated.

Answer (score 1):

One possible "workaround" that I'm currently investigating, myself—

- publish the hangout "on air"
- get the youtube live id (available as of 2012-08-22, roughly... since Hangout API 1.2) ~ `gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId()`  https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.onair#gapi.hangout.onair.getYouTubeLiveId (note that this can only be grabbed by the host?)
- grab `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=${LIVEID}` // suggestion: look at youtube-dl: http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/documentation.html
- and then use ffmpeg to process the flv

Information for this answer was primarily grabbed from [Downloading videos in flv format from youtube.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287748/downloading-videos-in-flv-format-from-youtube) and http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-plus-developers/128fbteedb/google-hangout-api-url-to-youtube-stream-screenshot-and-hangout-topic